# What does the circled 1 sign mean on Google maps next to "Tolls"?

Tags: driving, tolls, google-maps

What does the circled 1 sign mean on Google maps next to "Tolls"?

Example:

[image: we]

I don't think that's the number of tolls given the distance.

Comment: I've always assumed that it was a pictographic icon for tolls (representing coins or tokens), and that it had no particular meaning beyond that.

Comment: As @MichaelSeifert it is the symbol indicating there is tolls on your route.  Sometimes the symbol shows up to indicate tolls without also using the word "Tolls"

Comment: Have a fast and safe drive for such a long road!

Comment: Money. It used to come as round things with numbers on them...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As correctly stated by @MichaelSeifert, it is a graphic representation of coins.

A circle alone wouldn't be easily interpreted as currency. I **speculate** that using the dollar symbol would be biasing in an international context, so using a digit is the most intuitive way to display that the circle has **value**.

Historically, on US tollways you often used a single coin to pay the toll. Modern tollways are either more expensive or simply electronic (e.g., in Israel you don't have a single toll booth, and I found the same "1 coin" icon as I expected on my way from Tel Aviv to Haifa).

Comment: Interestingly that in Russia (and probably in some exUSSR countries) an auxiliary road sign for _paid_ parking shows 3 circles with numbers 10, 15 and 20 in them. There were actual 10-, 15- and 20-copeck coins in USSR (minted until 1991 and remained legal tender until 1998, although practically unused after 1992 due to extremely low value after hyperinflation).

Comment: This is probably correct. It's similar to the 'road toll' sign on Swedish roads (the coin bit at least): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockholm_congestion_tax#/media/File:Sweden_road_sign_E25.svg

Comment: They could display relevant country's currency on that icon, though. Yandex does that on its Maps.